# swi-prolog find all paths in grid

Tags: list, grid, prolog

I need to build all possible paths between two given points in a grid like this

```
 [1,1][2,1][3,1][4,1][5,1]
 [1,2][2,2][3,2][4,2][5,2]
 [1,3][2,3][3,3][4,3][5,3]
 [1,4][2,4][3,4][4,4][5,4]
 [1,5][2,5][3,5][4,5][5,5]
```

I have a utility thing (whatever that is) called `doesnt_contain` which checks if the element is already in the path in order to avoid loops. I try to start from the given point and at every step I want to go north, south east and west. When the target is met, I add the path to the list of all possible paths. Here is the code:

```
doesnt_contain([], _, _).
doesnt_contain([[H1|[H2|_]]|T], X, Y):- (X =\= H1; Y =\= H2), doesnt_contain(T, X, Y).
doesnt_contain([[H1|[H2|_]]|_], X, Y):- X == H1, Y == H2, fail.

build_paths(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, _, L, AL):- X1 =:= X2, Y1 =:= Y2, write([L|AL]).
build_paths(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, Limit, L, AL):-
    (X1 =\= X2; Y1 =\= Y2),
    ((X1 < Limit, X is X1 + 1, doesnt_contain(L, X, Y1), 
    build_paths(X, Y1, X2, Y2, Limit, [[X, Y1]|L], AL));
    (Y1 < Limit, Y is Y1 + 1, doesnt_contain(L, X1, Y), 
    build_paths(X1, Y, X2, Y2, Limit, [[X1, Y]|L], AL));
    (X1 > 1, X is X1 - 1, doesnt_contain(L, X, Y1), 
    build_paths(X, Y1, X2, Y2, Limit, [[X, Y1]|L], AL));
    (Y1 > 1, Y is Y1 - 1, doesnt_contain(L, X1, Y), 
    build_paths(X1, Y, X2, Y2, Limit, [[X1, Y]|L], AL))).
```

And one example of output with parameters in this order: (start X), (start Y), (end X), (end Y), (grid limit), (initial path including the start), (the list of all paths).

```
?- build_paths(2, 2, 4, 4, 5, [[2,2]], []).
[[[4,4],[3,4],[2,4],[1,4],[1,5],[2,5],[3,5],[4,5],[5,5],[5,4],[5,3],[5,2],[4,2],[3,2],[2,2]]]
true .
```

This code gives me one path and then it stops. I need all possible paths. I think I know why  it stops after the first path is found. It's because of the or (;) operator. But I have no idea how to make it generate all paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to clean up your code...

```
build_paths(P, P, _, L) :- !, writeln(L).
build_paths(P1, P2, Limit, Ps) :-
    move(P1, P, Limit),
    \+ memberchk(P, Ps),
    build_paths(P, P2, Limit, [P|Ps]).

move([X1,Y1], [X,Y], Limit) :-
    X1 < Limit, X is X1 + 1, Y is Y1 ;
    Y1 < Limit, Y is Y1 + 1, X is X1 ;
    X1 > 1, X is X1 - 1, Y is Y1 ;
    Y1 > 1, Y is Y1 - 1, X is X1.
```

calling it with

```
?- aggregate(count, build_paths([2, 2], [4, 4], 5, []), CountSol).
```

I get

```
...
[[4,4],[3,4],[3,3],[4,3],[4,2],[4,1],[3,1],[3,2],[2,2],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[1,5],[1,4],[1,3],[1,2],[1,1],[2,1]]
[[4,4],[5,4],[5,5],[4,5],[3,5],[3,4],[3,3],[4,3],[4,2],[4,1],[3,1],[3,2],[2,2],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[1,5],[1,4],[1,3],[1,2],[1,1],[2,1]]
[[4,4],[4,5],[3,5],[3,4],[3,3],[4,3],[4,2],[4,1],[3,1],[3,2],[2,2],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[1,5],[1,4],[1,3],[1,2],[1,1],[2,1]]
CountSol = 18184.
```

What is worth to note is mainly the separation between generation and test. You're tying  together the position update and the check, and that make your code much more error prone.

Comment: WOW. Thank you so much. No matter which programming language I use, I always try to break the solution into small pieces as much as I can. But the problem with prolog is that I can't use functions to return stuff. So I am forced to do the whole thing in one piece.